# AWS DMS - Task Failed for Oracle CDC maximum retry counter exceeded

Tags: amazon-web-services, oracle, amazon-rds, aws-dms, oracle-cdc

I'm running and ongoing replication form Oracle to RDS PostgresSQL and I already enable CDC on Oracle source DB and I enable the Minimal Supplemental Logging for database level.

But afther to run my full load task and start the ongoing task I'm getting the below error:

```
Last Error ; Oracle CDC maximum retry counter exceeded.; Error executing source loop; Stream component failed at subtask 0, component st_0_HHPLLJLYAGI3IBZUH4CMM6XTFZTBFYOBGQ6WPII; Stream component 'st_0_HHPLLJLYAGI3IBZUH4CMM6XTFZTBFYOBGQ6WPII' terminated [reptask/replicationtask.c:3242] [1022301] Stop Reason FATAL_ERROR Error Level FATAL
```

Researching about this I foun the below documentations: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/dms/latest/userguide/CHAP_Troubleshooting.html#CHAP_Troubleshooting.Oracle.CDCStopped

is someine has any opinios, this will be welcome

Thanks